# How to create outlook calendar event with custom value?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins, outlook-calendar

I want to create the outlook calendar event with custom value. Because i need to get some value while open the event.

Is this possible to send the custom value while creating the event in outlook add in - calendar event.

```
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: CLIENT_ID, // Client Id of the registered application
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URL,
  },
};

const graphScopes = ["user.read", "mail.send", "openid", "profile"]; // An array of graph scopes
const msalApplication = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
const options = new MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions(graphScopes);

const authProvider = new ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider(
  msalApplication,
  options
);
const option = {
  authProvider, // An instance created from previous step
};
const client = Client.initWithMiddleware(option);
```

Example Event :

```
  let event = {
      "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
      "body": {
        "contentType": "HTML",
        "content": "Does mid month work for you?"
      },
      "start": {
        "dateTime": "2021-08-13T12:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
      },
      "end": {
        "dateTime": "2021-08-13T14:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
      },
      "location":{
        "displayName":"Harry's Bar"
      },
      "attendees": [
        {
          "emailAddress": {
            "address":"adelev@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            "name": "Adele Vance"
          },
          "type": "required"
        }
      ]
    };
    client.api("/me/events").post(event, (err, res) => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    });
```

I want to pass the custom value while create the event. Is this possible to create the event with custom value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create a Calendar event from custom data.